# Unable to run typescript build task: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to compile typescript code to JavaScript by following the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_typescript-hello-world).

I created the watch task to compile the .ts files on pressing `Ctrl+Shift+B`. However, I get the error after I run the task:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I understand the cause of the error, as the directory `Program Files` has spaces in it, and I need quotes around it.

How do I update the build command to run the compiler with proper path?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to update the VS Code's integrated shell settings.

1. Go to File > Preferences > Settings
2. Search for shell
3. Select the correct shell settings for your operating system.
4. Either comment out the `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"` property, or update it to escape the double quotes around the directory. In my case it was `Program Files` directory which was causing trouble.